# How to convert json format to php array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a file of data.json that contain the data like these

```
    "meta": [
        "rectime",
        "strid",
        "ambt",
        "stri",
        "b1",
        "b2",
        "b3",
        "b4"
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            1377597739,
            1,
            0,
            77,
            816,
            13791,
            13794,
            13945
        ],
        [
            1377597739,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            816,
            13744,
            13725,
            13898
        ]
    ]
}
```

and I want to convert this data into PHP array like these

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/json");
$data = array(
  'John' => array(10,4,6,5), 
  'Jane' => array(3,4,2,3), 
  'Joe' => array(6,7,9,7)
);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

May anyone help me to suggest.

Thanks For your help

Comment: Are you asking about how to *parse* JSON in PHP?

Comment: You don't even have the names `John, Jane, Joe` in your data ... or is it all just crap? The numbers also don't fit.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer can be readily found by reading the [manual](http://php.net/json).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

**[See it in action](http://codepad.org/DCTMmgCm)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the one-liner:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"), true);
```

However, the snippet you have pasted from the file is not valid JSON.  Make sure that the input is actually valid JSON, or `json_decode()` will return `NULL`.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand correcttly

In file.php, I should change to this code.

<?php
header("Content-type: text/json");
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"), true);
echo json_encode($data);
?>

Comment: @ChunEiJi The PHP snippet you have is about *encoding* JSON, and it's not clear to me how this relates to your intended goal to "convert this data into PHP array."

Comment: I have external file data.json so I want to create a Highchart by using data in json. So I see some example that they use format of json like this. Then I want to convert my data.json to php array.

Sorry for my English. I'm a new one here

Comment: @ChunEiJi If your goal is to read in JSON data then why are you using `json_encode()`?